Responsibility for clearing gutters? (Landlord and Tenant Act 1985)
My tenancy agreement states that tenants are responsible for clearing gutters.
However, Landlord and Tenant Act 1985 suggests it's the landlord's responsibility.
I've asked chatGPT:

Cleaning gutters is generally the landlord's responsibility, as part of maintaining the structure and exterior of the property under the Landlord and Tenant Act 1985.
A tenancy agreement clause making it the tenant's responsibility may not be enforceable if it contradicts statutory obligations or is deemed unfair.

What is true? Can I refuse to clear the gutters, even if I have signed the contract?

For free advice about housing, it's better to contact an organisation such as Shelter or Citizens Advice than use software notorious for 'hallucinations'.

The Landlord and Tenant Act ("LTA") 1985 gives the following obligation to landlords:

Section 11(1)(a) of the LTA: The landlord must keep in repair the structure and exterior of the dwelling-house, including drains, gutters and external pipes.

This only applies if all of the following are met:

a) The tenant is on a "short lease". This means it must be granted for a term of less than seven years (see s 13(1) of the LTA)
b) There is disrepair or a failure of the gutters that affects the tenant's enjoyment of the dwelling.
c) The tenant has notified the landlord of specific disrepair to prompt action.
d) The tenant has not caused the disrepair or failure of the gutters
e) The problem with the gutters has not arisen out of an unforeseen "act of God" (e.g. a natural disaster)

Most critically to your question on whether or not the landlord is allowed to limit or exclude its liability for any of the above, we have the following:

Section 12(1) of the LTA: any covenant or agreement within a lease or other applicable agreement (subject to the conditions above) is void if it attempts to exclude or limit liability for its obligations under Section 11
(unless the inclusion of this provision was authorised by the county court)


So to summarise the above, based on what you have told us, this part of your tenancy agreement is void and you can refuse to clear the gutters. This is because your landlord is attempting to exclude their liability under Section 11 of the LTA, which is expressly prohibited (provided the conditions above are met). Moreover, you may be able to enforce the LTA against your landlord to ensure that they clear the gutters. However, before attempting to do so please be careful to check the exact details of your tenancy agreement against the LTA to ensure you fall within the scope of the Act. The above tells you the position in generality, and as I am not privy to all of the facts, you will have to apply them to your situation yourself (ideally with the help of independent legal advice).
I have attached a link here to the most recent version of the LTA for your reference

the "short lease" part seems to me (as a total layman, so please tell me if I'm reading it wrong!) like it would only apply to limited term leases - are those common in the UK? here (germany) I've only had a term-limited lease once (or rather, my parents did when I was a kid) and I've rented all my life, so "unlimited" feels like the default for me.

@Syndic Yes, limited is ubiquitous in the UK (or at least in England), typically contracts are for a year.  The advice in the question is true, but also not 100% useful, as the landlord can kick out any annoying tenant by simply not renewing the lease (yearly) or increasing the rent by 500% (same effect). In theory the tenant is in their right, in practice they might well be penalised with eviction at the end of their yearly lease for daring to resist, so whether complaining is wise in practice is another one.  England has nothing comparable to the German Mieterbund.

@gerrit Landlords cannot kick out tenants simply by not renewing the tenancy. In this case, it becomes periodic. They specifically need to evict the tenant (although obviously this is relatively easy, many landlords fail to do it correctly).

@MJeffryes OK, but with sufficient notice prior to the end of the tenancy, they can evict tenants without cause, as far as I understand.  But yes, if the landlord / letting agent does nothing, the tenancy becomes periodic.

@gerrit Yes, absolutely (in England) they can demand the tenant opts in to a new fixed term or issue a section 22 notice if they don't. But the tenancy cannot end 'passively' simply by failing to agree to a new fixed term (although it can end 'passively' if the tenant chooses to leave at the end of the fix term, which they may do without notice).

@gerrit: unreasonable rent increases, if done by the method specified in the Housing Act 1988 (section 13 notice), can be challenged by the tenant by taking the landlord to a tribunal, which can modify the proposed increase. As for evictions, MJeffyes has addressed that - though note that section 21 ("no fault") evictions are likely to be removed as an option in the next year or so.
